# Node form ajax dependent dropdown fields issue

Tags: nodes, hooks, ajax

I am using Drupal 9. I know how to change single dropdown list using another one. Here is my scenario:

I have three dropdowns, in node form - company, protocol and investigator. What I like to do, when some one select a value in company dropdown, other two dropdown list which change based on selection.

I have written some code, I see the list is updating but its not refreshing.

```
function hook_form_alter() {
    ....

    case 'node_tsr_form':
    case 'node_tsr_edit_form':
      $form['field_tsr_pi']['#prefix'] = '<div id="my-module-principal-investigator-wrapper">';
      $form['field_tsr_pi']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
      $form['field_protocol']['#prefix'] = '<div id="my-module-tsr-protocol-wrapper">';
      $form['field_protocol']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

      $form['field_company']['widget']['#ajax'] = [
        'callback' => 'my_module_ajax_callback_tsr_pi_and_protocol',
        'event' => 'change',
        'progress' => [
          'type' => 'throbber',
          'message' => t('loading ...'),
        ],
      ];
      $company_val = $form_state->getValue('field_company');
      if (isset($company_val[0]['target_id'])) {
        $company_id = $company_val[0]['target_id'];
      }

      if (!empty($company_id)) {
        $form['field_protocol']['widget']['#options'] = my_module_get_protocols($company_id);
        $form['field_pi']['widget']['#options'] = my_module_get_investigator($company_id);
      }
      else {
        $form['field_protocol']['widget']['#options'] = ['_none' => '- None -'];
        $form['field_pi']['widget']['#options'] = ['_none' => '- None -'];
      }
    ...

/**
 * Called via Ajax callback.
 */
function my_module_ajax_callback_tsr_pi_and_protocol(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $company_val = $form_state->getValue('field_company');

  if (isset($company_val[0]['target_id'])) {
    $company_id = $company_val[0]['target_id'];
  }
  if (!empty($company_id)) {
    $form['field_protocol']['widget']['#options'] = my_module_get_approved_aup_options($company_id);
    $form['field_tsr_pi']['widget']['#options'] = my_module_get_acitve_user_options($company_id);
  }
  else {
    $form['field_protocol']['widget']['#options'] = ['_none' => '- None -'];
    $form['field_tsr_pi']['widget']['#options'] = ['_none' => '- None -'];
  }

  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#my-module-tsr-protocol-wrapper',$form['field_protocol']));
  $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#my-module-principal-investigator-wrapper', $form['field_tsr_pi']));

  return $response;
}
```

If anyone can help me out, will be really great!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually fix my issue:

```
function hook_form_alter() {
    ....

    case 'node_tsr_form':
    case 'node_tsr_edit_form':
      $form['field_tsr_pi']['#prefix'] = '<div id="my-module-principal-investigator-wrapper">';
      $form['field_tsr_pi']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
      $form['field_protocol']['#prefix'] = '<div id="my-module-tsr-protocol-wrapper">';
      $form['field_protocol']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

      $form['field_company']['widget']['#ajax'] = [
        'callback' => 'my_module_ajax_callback_tsr_pi_and_protocol',
        'event' => 'change',
        'method' => 'html',
        'progress' => [
          'type' => 'throbber',
          'message' => t('loading ...'),
        ],
      ];
      $form['field_protocol']['widget']['#validated'] = TRUE;
      $form['field_tsr_strain']['widget']['#validated'] = TRUE;
    ...

/**
 * Called via Ajax callback.
 */
function my_module_ajax_callback_tsr_pi_and_protocol(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $company_val = $form_state->getValue('field_company');

  if (isset($company_val[0]['target_id'])) {
    $company_id = $company_val[0]['target_id'];
  }

  // Update Member(s) to notify options.
  $protocols = '';
  $pis = '';
  if (!empty($company_id)) {
    $protocol_data = vivarium_get_approved_aup_options($company_id);
    foreach ($protocol_data as $key => $value) {
      $protocols .= "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";
    }

    $pis_list = vivarium_get_acitve_user_options($company_id);
    foreach ($pis_list as $key => $value) {
      $pis .= "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";
    }
  }
  else {
    $protocols = "<option value='_none>- None -</option>";
    $pis = "<option value='_none>- None -</option>";
  }

  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand("#my-module-tsr-protocol-wrapper select", $protocols));
  $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand("#my-module-principal-investigator-wrapper select", $pis));

  return $response;
}
```